# JQuery HasAttribute Selector with Attribute Length

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tooltip, jquery-events

Currently I'm developing a custom tooltip for my website. It's a heavy one, so it has around 300 elements with title on every page. And It's working well with this code:

```
var title="";
$( document ).delegate( "[title]", "mouseover", function ( event ) {
    title = $( this ).attr( "title" );
    $( "#tooltip-div" ).delay( 250 ).animate( { top: newTop, opacity: 1 }, 'fast' );
 } );
```

But the problem I'm facing is:
Unfortunately, there are many elements in the page which have the title attribute, but empty. For example:

```
<input type="image" id="clearBtn" title="" src="../../Images/unsearch.png" onclick="clearFilter();">
```

For this  element, my custom tooltip is showing up with an empty value.
So I was wondering if there is any way to select elements which have the 'title' attribute and that attribute is not empty.

So I want to exclude the elements like the one I show above. Is there a way to do that directly using a JQuery Selector, to make sure that I bind the event only to my desired elements, other that checking the length of title attribute inside the event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, requiring a `[title]`, and a `[title!='']`.

```
var title="";
$( document ).delegate("[title][title!='']", "mouseover", function ( event ) {
    title = $( this ).attr( "title" );
    $( "#tooltip-div" ).delay( 250 ).animate( { top: newTop, opacity: 1 }, 'fast' );
});
```

Comment: Cheers, @Shree - Tested it and both the `[title]` selector and the `[title!='']` selector are required.  Using just the `[title!='']` selector will match all elements with no title.

Answer (score 1):

the previous solution (which is similar to use [:not selector from CSS 3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp)) is valid, but it's not considering the following cases ([See example at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hbjp/) ):

```
<a href="#" title=' '>anchor 1</a>
<span title='  '>anchor 2</span>
```

So, if you want to do a thorough checkup of title value, you do could use length and trim but using jquery each method:

```
$('[title]').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).attr('title').trim();
  if (title =! '') {
    $(this).on("mouseover", function(event) {
      title = $( this ).attr( "title" );
      $("#tooltip-div").delay( 250 ).animate( { top: newTop, opacity: 1 }, 'fast' );
    })
  }

});
```

Also, note that [As of jQuery 1.7, delegate method, has been superseded by the .on() method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: Thanks for the interest. But the last solution fixed my problem. +1;